# Facebook App Review: Privacy Policy for app without UI

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know this is not a strictly code-related question but I wonder if anyone here could help.
As you know FB has updated his policy and app now must undergone a review process.
We were about to send our app for review for Public Content Access but now we are in a dilemma:our "server-to-server" app does not involve a UI and only aims to help our operations team with a small integration to our CRM: checking the presence of our customers (always other companies) in the platform. 
The app will store only, if exists, the link to the FB public page of the company.
What kind of privacy policy we need? Do we need one?
Otherwise, are there any facebook contacts for developers looking for help?

Thank you for your time!